# Change less variable on azure website

Tags: css, less, azure-web-app-service

Him

I have two azure website (Web app). Test and production, I need have test red header and on production have green header. What is best practice to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Can you be more more specific ? I saw that you tagged `css` but did't talk about it anywhere. I suggest you to improve a little more this question, posting a piece of your code and pointing where you are having problems...

Comment: since you have two websites, append another class to the header (test for example) and in your css other than [header class]{background:green;} create a class for [header class].test{background:red} so that in your test website the header will have the red color. Abviously this is a general idea, just take this as a starting point

Comment: @Nick I have two site but one code, it development enviroment. I do not know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can read the WEBSITE_SITE_NAME environment variable in your backend and use that to conditionally show the UI you want.

WEBSITE_SITE_NAME will be set to the name of your site, so you can check to see if the name matches your test site's name to know if you should show the red header or the green.

You can get the full list of environment variables available to your Azure Website at `http://<yourSiteName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env`